# MongoDB, properly setting OneToMany, ManyToOne relations methods

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I'm trying to properly setup oneToMany, ManyToOne relation method, so far my result (pseudocode below). I'm using Typegoose (basically is it Mongoose with types), if you never used it before, it's nothing to worry about, this would be about architecture anyway. I wanna discuss "createBook" method, as you can see, I'm using "await, await" in sequence which makes it really inefficient, I can use promises and at the end of the method write `Promise.all(bookQuery, authorQuery)`, but I still have a problem with error handling, what if one of them fail, other still can succeed, which is not good (properly: if one them fail, other should retrieve any changes, which that made). How I should properly, efficiently write "createBook" method?

```
class Author extends Typegoose {
  @prop()
  fullName: string;

  @prop({ ref: Book, default: [] })
  books: Ref<Book>[];
}

class Book extends Typegoose {
  @prop()
  title: string;

  @prop({ ref: Author })
  author: Ref<Author>;
}

async createBook(title, authorId): Promise<Book> {
    const book = await new this.bookRepository({
      title,
      author: ObjectId(authorId)
    }).save();

    await this.authorRepository.updateOne(
      { _id: authorId },
      { $push: { books: Types.ObjectId(book.id) } }
    );

    return book;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First way is this

```js
async createBook(title, authorId): Promise<Book> {
  const book = new this.bookRepository({
    title,
    author: ObjectId(authorId)
  }).save();

  const author = this.authorRepository.updateOne(
    { _id: authorId },
    { $push: { books: Types.ObjectId(book.id) } }
  );
  try {
    await Promise.all([book, author])
    return book;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    await Promise.all([
      this.bookRepository.deleteOne({_id: book._id}),
      this.authorRepository.updateOne(
        { _id: authorId },
        { $pull: { books: Types.ObjectId(book.id) } 
      }
    )]
  }
}
```

The second way is to use [MongoDB Transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/transactions/). However, it comes from Mongo 4.0 version and it used only on Replica Set. In addition, from 4.2 version Transactions will be available also on sharded collections